# Is the Cartesian product of two bounded sets bounded? What about for compact sets?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

The title pretty much speaks for itself. I just got this curiosity while self-studying Real Analysis using Baby Rudin and Charles Pugh's "Real Mathematical Analysis" out of boredom. I am still relatively new to abstract math since these two books are my first brush with the subject.

Comment: yes, it is true

Comment: Yes, the product of any family of compact topological spaces is compact. This is Tychonoff's theorem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $A,B\subseteq\Bbb R$ are bounded, there is a positive integer $n$ such that $A\cup B\subseteq[-n,n]$. Then

$$A\times B\subseteq[-n,n]\times[-n,n]\subseteq\left\{\langle x,y\rangle\in\Bbb R^2:x^2+y^2\le 2n^2\right\}\;,$$

and that last set is plainly bounded: it is the closed disk of radius $n\sqrt2$ centred at the origin.

It is a basic result in topology that the product of two compact sets is compact. Indeed, the product of any family of compact sets, no matter how large, is compact: this is the very important Tikhonov theorem.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but does the boundedness of the Cartesian product apply to any subsets of any metric space X?

Comment: @LamNg.: That depends on how you define the metric on the product. Suppose that $X=(0,1)$. Then every subset of $X$ is bounded in the usual metric and in any of the usual product metrics, but $(0,1)^2$ is homeomorphic to $\Bbb R^2$, so there are metrics on $X^2$ that generate the product topology and do **not** preserve boundedness.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is [Tychonoff's Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tychonoff%27s_theorem). Indeed, the product of any (possibly uncountable) family of compact sets is compact under the [product topology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Product_topology) (though, beware that products of open sets are not necessarily in the product topology).

Answer (score 0):

Let $X$, $Y$ be compact spaces and suppose you have a covering of $X\times Y$ by open subsets $\{U_i|i\in I\}$.  We will show that this cover contains a finite subcover.

By definition of the product topology, each $U_i$ is a union of open sets of the form $W\times Z$ with $W\subseteq X$, $Z\subseteq Y$ open in their respective spaces.  Let $\{V_j|j\in J\}$ be all the open sets of the form $W\times Z$, which are contained in some $U_i$. Then the $V_j$ form a cover of $X \times Y$.

We will show that a finite number of $V_j$ cover $X\times Y$.  It follows immediately that a finite number of $U_i$ cover $X\times Y$: for each $V_j$ in the finite cover, just take one $U_i$ with $U_i\supseteq V_j$.

Given $x\in X$ we may cover $\{x\}\times Y$ with a finite number of $V_j$ (by compactness of $Y$).  Denote these open sets: $$\{W_i \times Z_i| i=1,\cdots, r\}$$ with $r$ a natural number, and each $W_i\subseteq X$, $Z_i\subseteq Y$ open.  Then let: $$W_x=\bigcap_{i=1}^rW_i$$

Our finite set of $V_j$ now cover $W_x\times Y$.

The $\{W_x|x\in X\}$ cover $X$. By compactness of $X$, for some finite set $\{x_1,\cdots,x_k\} \subseteq X$, the $W_{x_i}$ cover $X$.  By construction, for each $i=1,\cdots, k$ we have a finite cover of $W_{x_i}\times Y$ with open sets $V_j$.  Combining these $k$ sets of finite sets of $V_j$, we get a finite set of $V_j$ which cover $X \times Y$.